# SSMS 2014 Connect to SQL 2008 R2 Edit Job Step SQL Server Integration Service Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This issue has just started happening with my environment. Here are the players.
Desktop: windows 8 with SSMS 2014.
Server: Windows 2012 with SQL 2008R2.

I could until a few days ago would go in the SQL's Job Activity Monitor. Edit a Job's Step. Changing the location of the SSIS package. Now I get this error.

I'm NOT running SQL 2005 but the error claims I am.

```
    ===================================

    Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "PRD-WIN-SQL-20" failed with the following error: "Class not registered".

    This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


    ------------------------------
    For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220763

    ------------------------------
    Program Location:

       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetDtsServerPackageInfos(String sPackageFolder, String sServerName)
       at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls.GeneralViewCtrl.<>c__DisplayClass4.<buttonBrowse_Click>b__1(String path)
       at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls.GeneralViewCtrl.buttonBrowse_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

    ===================================

    Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "PRD-WIN-SQL-20" failed with the following error: "Class not registered".

    This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.


    ------------------------------
    Program Location:

       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.GetDtsServerPackageInfos(String bstrPackageFolder, String bstrServerName)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetDtsServerPackageInfos(String sPackageFolder, String sServerName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is limited backwards compatibility between SSMS 2012 (and I'm assuming 2014) and earlier versions of Integration Services. See here for an explanation and a workaround:

http://www.ssistalk.com/2012/03/21/connecting-to-a-pre-sql-2012-ssis-instance-with-sql-2012-ssms/

Also, just because your SQL Server is version 2008 R2 doesn't mean your Integration Services was updated. It could still be the 2005 version of Integration Services. See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280546.aspx

Comment: So do you think I update my desktop version of "MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml" or the server one.  Because they both have been changed and restarted.  STILL nothing.  I'm also NOT using sql 2005.  I'm trying to assign a package to a job.

Comment: @MichaelKramer I understand what you are trying to do. Please go to this page and follow the instructions for Method 1 and tell me what the version number is: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942177 The version number will be after the server name, like `ServerName (Integration Services _version number_ - domain\user`

Comment: The Service Version is: 10.50.2550

Comment: I think that is your issue. Check out that first link I posted and see if your workaround works. SSMS 2012 and later has problems connecting to older versions of Integration Services. Why it says 2005, I'm not sure, but even though you're running 2008 R2, it appears that is still an issue. When you modify a SQL Agent job, I believe SSMS needs to connect to Integration Services, which is when your error occurs. You should be able to use SSMS 2008 without issue.